# C++ access violation to array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, memory-management, access-violation

I'm a newbie in C++, and I try to create an array of objects. I use a code like

```
const int SORT_SIZE = 20;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CSimple * data;
    data = new CSimple[SORT_SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < SORT_SIZE; i++)
    {
/*Access violation here*/   *(data + i * (sizeof(CSimple))) = *(new CSimple(rand() % 10000));
    }
```

and in my cycle on i = 5 i get access violation. sizeof(CSimple) is 8 (there's only one int field there) if it matters

Comment: Sorry, deleting my answer - after rereading your code there was enough wrong with what I said that it was better to just delete.

Comment: Take out the `* (sizeof(CSimple)`

Comment: @PaulR is right. The compiler takes care of scaling the integer operand of pointer arithmetic operations by the size of the pointed-to object, so when you do it also, you're moving further than you think you are.

Comment: Oh, and sorry @PaulR for you answer too. I just don't understand you at the beginning but now i see you were right also! So hard to be a newbie:) Thank yoU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line within the for-loop with `data[i] = CSimple(rand() % 10000)`. Much more readabale, isn't it?

The reason your code failed is because `data + i` does not increment data by i bytes but by i `CSimple`'s. Say, if CSimple is four bytes long, then `data + i * sizeof(CSimple)` would increment data by 16 bytes instead of 4.

Comment: `&data[i]`, no?  Edit:  no, memory already aloc'ed, so delete `new`.

Comment: @djechlin Edit: It seems we were both incorrect (and corrected ourselves simultaniously).

Answer (score -2):

As a newbie, why don't you make your life easier and use types that do the hard work for you automatically?

```
#include <vector>

const int SORT_SIZE = 20;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<CSimple> data;

    for(int i = 0; i < SORT_SIZE; i++)
    {
        data.push_back( CSimple(rand() % 10000) );
    }
```